# how to make my windows 7 recovery disk bootable?

Tags: windows-7, uefi, bootmgr

I am getting this error "bootmgr is missing".  did some research on google, the fix is easy, create a windows 7 recovery disk, it should fix that problem.

after created the recovery disk, I cannot boot using this recovery disk.  my motherboard p8p67 pro is using UEFI.  seems like its a known issue that recovery disk is useless if you are using UEFI.

I got stuck here. need help to boot from recovery disk, so I can fix the bootmgr is missing issue.

Comment: What happens when you change the boot order and enable Legacy Bios ( or some similar named feature ) mode?

Comment: i didn't know how to enable legacy bios. I went to uefi  coudln't find any options let you do that.

Comment: Its in the CSM section. Where did you hear recovery disks are useless if you are using UEFI anyways?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so try this. Boot into BIOS and look for anything labeled `Secure Boot` or `UEFI` and disable it. Then you can choose your boot media or change the boot order.

Comment: not able to find them in uefi bios.

Comment: Try EasyBCD (Easy Boot CD) 2.2 - recommended from this link: http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1726371